# How to search value from array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an issue while comparing two array and print result using php. I am explaining my code below.

```
$comment = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '2', 'comment' => 'vodka1'), array('day_id' => '3', 'comment' => 'vodka2')));
$result = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '1', 'restaurant' => '193'), array('day_id' => '2', 'restaurant' => '193'), array('day_id' => '3', 'restaurant' => '193')));
$arrComment = json_decode($comment, true);
$arrResult = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($arrResult AS $keyResult => $dataResult){
    $day_id = $dataResult['day_id'];
    $restaurant = $dataResult['restaurant'];
    $strComment = '';
    $getKey='';
    $getKey = array_search($day_id, array_column($arrComment, 'day_id'));
    if($getKey ==''){
        $strComment = '';
    }else{
        $strComment = $arrComment[$getKey]['comment'];
    }
     $insertintodetails[]=array("day_id"=>$day_id,"rest"=>$restaurant,"comment"=>$strComment);
}
echo json_encode($insertintodetails);
```

Here i am getting the below result.

```
[{"day_id":"1","rest":"193","comment":""},{"day_id":"2","rest":"193","comment":""},{"day_id":"3","rest":"193","comment":"vodka2"}]
```

But my result should come like below.

```
[{"day_id":"1","rest":"193","comment":""},{"day_id":"2","rest":"193","comment":"vodka1"},{"day_id":"3","rest":"193","comment":"vodka2"}]
```

Here my requirement is if `day_id from $result` is not present in `$comment` then the respective comment field will remain blank. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it will work fine. here `array_search()` always return key or boolean (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

So just need to check `$getKey` is false or any key.

```
$comment = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '2', 'comment' => 'vodka1'), array('day_id' => '3', 'comment' => 'vodka2')));
$result = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '1', 'restaurant' => '193'), array('day_id' => '2', 'restaurant' => '193'), array('day_id' => '3', 'restaurant' => '193')));
$arrComment = json_decode($comment, true);
$arrResult = json_decode($result, true);

foreach($arrResult as $keyResult => $dataResult){
    $day_id = $dataResult['day_id'];
    $restaurant = $dataResult['restaurant'];
    $strComment = '';
    $getKey='';
    $getKey = array_search($day_id, array_column($arrComment, 'day_id'));

    if(is_numeric($getKey)){
        $strComment = $arrComment[$getKey]['comment'];
    }else{
        $strComment = '';
    }
     $insertintodetails[]=array("day_id"=>$day_id,"rest"=>$restaurant,"comment"=>$strComment);
}
echo json_encode($insertintodetails);
```